# Visual Studio loads files running in debug mode but not in run without debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Put most simply with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::ifstream ifs;

    ifs.open("test.txt");

    if( !ifs ){
        std::cout << "Error";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Success";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I choose Start Debugging I get "Success", when I choose Start Without Debugging I get "Error". Running Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012. I would add more information if I knew where to look but I am not a Visual Studio guy so I don't know what to look for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem revolves around the "test.txt" wherever you have. Normally if you have this file in Working directory (your project directory where you will find your .cpp files) it should work with both Release and Debug.

"Start Debugging F5" looks for "test.txt" in both project folder and "Debug" folder whereas "Start without Debugging Ctrl+F5" only looks for "test.txt" in project folder.

Instead placing file like above, try giving full path of the file in your code something like this,

```
ifs.open("C:\\Test\\test.txt");
```

Update (11 Apr 2015):
Modified the answer based on "paid nerd" (!!!) comments (please check below).

Comment: Good idea, but "Start without debugging" doesn't seem to use any of the configuration properties under Debugging.

Comment: "@ a paid nerd" Thanks for pointing it out. My bad, didnt get the question clearly. Updated the answer.